# user return for temperature conversion with Java

Tags: java

I want to create a program that converts temperatures from fahrenheit to celsius and gives the user the option to continue giving temperatures until they choose not to. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConversions 
{
private static int temperature;
private static int fahrenheit;


public TempConversions () 
{
fahrenheit = 0;
temperature = 0;

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    MayenHeading.getHeading("Assignment 4 ");

    System.out.printf("  Temperature Converter\n");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("\n  Enter temperature to convert -->   ");
    temperature = sc.nextInt();



    fahrenheit = ((temperature - 32)*5)/9;
    System.out.printf("  The temperature is " + fahrenheit + " degrees                           fahrenheit");

    // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("\n  Continue? (y/n): ");
        String choice = sc.next();

    {   
    System.out.printf("\n  Program completed.");
    MayenDate.printfDate();
    MayenDate.printfTime();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: OK, and what is your question? In what way does this code not do what you want?

Comment: Incidentally, you seem to be converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius, then printing the result as a Fahrenheit temperature.

Comment: Yes but the program ends after 1 conversion. I want it to ask the user if they want to continue and if so then they enter another number to convert if not then they have the option to opt out.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `do while` loop for that

```
public class TempConversions 
        {
        private static int temperature;
        private static int fahrenheit;


        public TempConversions () 
        {
        fahrenheit = 0;
        temperature = 0;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            MayenHeading.getHeading("Assignment 4 ");

    do{


            System.out.printf("  Temperature Converter\n");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.printf("\n  Enter temperature to convert -->   ");
            temperature = sc.nextInt();



            fahrenheit = ((temperature - 32)*5)/9;
            System.out.printf("  The temperature is " + fahrenheit + " degrees                           fahrenheit");

            // see if the user wants to continue
                System.out.print("\n  Continue? (y/n): ");
                String choice = sc.next();
        }while(choice.chatAt(0) == 'y');
            {   
            System.out.printf("\n  Program completed.");
            MayenDate.printfDate();
            MayenDate.printfTime();
            }

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way I would do it is assign a constant as your exit variable eg

```
Final int EXIT = 1;
```

This allows you to make quick changes in the future let's say you have many options and need to use 1 you just simple change one to anything else rather than finding 1 multiple times in your program.
So I'll write some framework for you below to follow to get your code to do what you want.

```
Public static void main(String []args)
{

     Public final int EXIT = 1;

      //Declare your other variables
      //Declare any other classes your using
       //Start of a do while loop
       Do
        {

             // Your conversion program goes here
              //Prompt user for exit


         }
         while(choice != EXIT)

   }//End of main
```

The logic I have for doing a do while loop over a while loop or a for loop is you need to execute this at least once.
If you didn't or if you knew how many times the user wanted to loop you would use one of the other kind of loop.

Comment: Okay so I got everything I want it to do except in the end. I want the user to enter (00) to end the program or (F) to continue and enter another value to convert.

Comment: You'll need an if statement at the end of the loop. If(choice == 'F') Display continue message else display exiting message

Comment: You'll make choice a char variable and change the constant to a char as well